# BackgroundWorker blocking NotifyIcon's ContextMenu

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker, notifyicon

I have a WinForms app with the following (skeleton) code:

```
namespace MyTrayApp
{
    public class SysTrayApp : Form
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                SysTrayApp app = new SysTrayApp();
                Application.Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private NotifyIcon _trayIcon;
        private ContextMenu _trayMenu;

        private BackgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        public SysTrayApp()
        {
            _trayMenu = new ContextMenu();
            _trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Exit", OnExit);

            _trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
            _trayIcon.Icon = new Icon(SystemIcons.Asterisk, 40, 40);

            _trayIcon.ContextMenu = _trayMenu;
            _trayIcon.Visible = true;

            _bw.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
            _bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            _bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
            _bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
        // do stuff
        }

        private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
            return;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)); // wait 5 minutes...
            _bw.RunWorkerAsync(); // then run again
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can only right-click to open the ContextMenu when the app starts up. It seems that once the BackgroundWorker starts sleeping, it somehow blocks the ContextMenu. Thoughts?

Comment: Put the Thread.Sleep statement in the DoWork function. That's the function that executes in a background thread.

Comment: It would work, and I consider that a valid answer.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Do you want to execute something in the background every 5 minutes or did you want to use `Thread.Sleep` temporarily to _simulate_ work?

Comment: I want to wait 5 minutes, as my comments in code say.

Comment: Then a timer is the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep` is executed on the gui(main) thread (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx) due to the way you've cread the BGW You should use a Timer instead Thread.Sleep 5 minutes.

Timer Class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

Comment: Doesn't this look like a question back?

Comment: I could write the first parts as comment, the second as answer, i did combine it.

Comment: Convince me that the `Sleep` is executed on the GUI thread and you've got yourself at the least an upvote.

Comment: Just execute this: Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); on the Constructor and the bw_RunWorkerCompleted. If the Id's are the same, then it's the same thread.

Comment: @KingKing that was when his answer was just "Isn't the Thread.Sleep executed on the gui(main)thread? You should use a Timer instead", which I'm pretty sure SO doesn't think is a good enough answer. Adding a link to the Timer class is *getting* there...

Comment: Ultimately, I think my problem is best solved by having a `Timer` trigger my `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork`, which is not described in this answer.

Comment: More specifically `RunWorkerCompleted` executes on the same thread that created the` BackgroundWorker` object (see reference in answer).

Comment: as a side fyi [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) has the same behavior.